# Program/algorithm to find the time complexity of any given program

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I like to know whether it is possible to "write a **program** or **algorithm**" **to find the time complexity** of any given program taken as input.

**Input :** any program (P) [in any language or of a particular language]

**Output :** time complexity of that program (P).

Have there been any prior attempts to write such a program?
Are there any algorithms available for this purpose?

If so please provide the necessary links, references or with any kind of guidance possible.

Comment: Similiar to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480775/programmatically-obtaining-big-o-efficiency-of-code

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331801/why-does-the-halting-problem-make-it-impossible-for-software-to-determine-the-ti

Answer (score 30):

No. It's not possible. This is a form of the [halting problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: +1: Until you can prove the program P halts, you can't prove anything about it's time complexity.

Comment: But for a non-turing complete language it might be possible :) (and it's an open question how useful such languages might be)

Comment: Ignoring the theoretical bs about the halting problem. It would seem that you could make a program that would give you a rough estimate and just assume the program will eventually ends.

Comment: @corymatthews: No.  You can't get a "rough estimate".  You either have a program that you can argue for the complexity -- as a mathematical exercise -- and be right.  Or you have a program which you cannot prove terminates; in which case you can't do anything more.

Comment: If cory's program existed, then even if it only worked for problems known to halt, then it would solve that irritating P=NP question once and for all. Just run it against the "try every single program that exists in pseudo-parallel" algorithm for the travelling salesman problem, and find out whether that has polynomial complexity. If so, P=NP, if not P!=NP. Since P=NP is not solved, no such program exists.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You're wrong, your method could not decide P=NP, mainly because there are infinitely many such programs.

Comment: @jpalacek: I'm talking about a program whose input is an instance of TSP, and that dovetails every single program that exists (of which there are countably many), and tests the result of each (as and when it completes, if it does) to see whether it solves that instance of TSP. There's more than one way to write that program, but all of them have the property that they have polynomial complexity if and only if P=NP. So if cory's oracle exists, see what "rough estimate" it gives for one such program, and you have a "rough estimate" of whether P=NP. Whatever "rough estimate" means.

Comment: Any other NP-complete problem would do in place of TSP, of course -- the decision version of TSP is NP-complete. The whole point of the dovetailing technique is to run countably many programs "in parallel" on a deterministic machine. Note that my whole proposal falls squarely under the heading of "theoretical bs about the halting problem" that cory sets aside - he wasn't seriously proposing an infallible test, I'm just pointing out how I know that no such infallible test is known.

Comment: this has **nothing to do** with the halting problem, where the decision *subroutine* must be able to refer to the whole program which must be able to use/refer to the decision subroutine (only then the paradoxical degenerate program can be constructed proving the impossibility of the halting decision subroutine). Here the decision *program* is entirely extraneous to the program being analyzed which doesn't even know about the decision program, much less is able to refer to it.

Answer (score 4):

Proving the complexity of an arbitrary algorithm is not possible but in principle you could estimate it:

1. choose n, the size of the input
2. run the algorithm
3. observe t(n), the time needed to run the algorithm for input of size n
4. choose another n, repeat steps 2 and 3 until you have a lot of data
5. regress t(n) on n, n^k, log(n), n log(n), n!, or any other 
   term that might be appropriate
6. choose a term with statistical significance and declare that 
   to be your estimated complexity of the algorithm

There are any number of pitfalls to this approach

1. This will not prove anything, only estimate
2. If t(n) gets really large for large n, it will take a long time to
   collect enough data for your analysis
3. There are many ways that this approach can be fooled unless you use huge values
   of n. For example, this algorithm will look like O(1) unless you use astronomical
   values for n

   ```
   sleep for 10 days
   run an O(n log(n)) sorting algorithm
   ```

And other SO users can come up with many more. But in some cases, like when you do a complexity analysis of an algorithm and want to verify it empirically, this is still a useful approach.

Comment: The problem is step 3: you can't be certain that the program will *ever* halt for arbitrary input.  This is the halting problem.  The consequence is that even this estimation method won't, in general, produce a useful measure.

Comment: Worse, there are terminating algorithms that will still take until heat death of the universe to produce their answer.  You should probably know this before you start trying to run it and gather data.

Comment: True, but if you had a tolerance say MAX t(n) the method could be used to make the estimate for times less than t(n) (Just force kill the process after Max t(n) time). It won't tell you if the program will halt, but you will discover either the running time of the algorithm of get a result of "this program runs so long that it's effectively non-usable for me" .

Comment: I wouldn't say this isn't useful in general. Most algorithms that you want to benchmark will trivially halt. As mobrule pointed out, this doesn't prove anything about runtimes, but it does provide a useful statistical test.

Comment: And for practical purposes, asymptotic behaviour is in any case completely, utterly irrelevant. I have literally never written a program where I care about its runtime if that runtime exceeds a year, and a year is well short of the limit as N tends to infinity. If your so-called algorithm doesn't halt for some inputs, then you have worse problems than that you can't measure its apparent complexity (for small N) by this method...

Comment: local empirical asymptotic behaviour is a useful extrapolation measure for running time, and easy enough to find as `k = log (t2/t1) / log (n2/n1)` for local `O(n^k)` behaviour (taken as run times `t1,t2` at problem sizes `n1,n2`).

Answer (score 0):

can't we introduce some more variables in the algorithm itself and find the complexity the same way we do it manually.
like for example we can have a variable in an insertion sort say n=0 which keeps the track of the entire looping part of the algorithm and then give the answer as O(n^2)

Comment: you still have to run it on many different inputs. It being self-observant instead of you manually calculating the averages does't change *that* fact. But if your routine lives inside some kind of dynamic system which is constantly in use then yes, self-observancy/awareness is a very good idea, IMO. The *supervisor* part of a system would observe and detect which parts need improvement, and choose another algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

Well I think you do this by assuming all cases.
1:Like first make a module which can extract each of the instruction
2: Do make a database of instruction to match up with the program instruction.
3: calculate the complexity by fetching the appropriate time complexity set by you in database and that's all.