# Program to fnd Time Complexity of a java program

Tags: java, time-complexity

I've been trying to write a simple program in java to find time complexity of a program.A program whih just searches for "for" loop or "while" loop and prints the no of iteration such as O(n) or O(2n) etc.

I got the i/p program in textarea.Is there any way by which i could do the opertaion?

Please any one help me.

Comment: What do you have exactly? What is "the i/p program"?

Comment: FYI O(n) and O(2n) are the same.

Comment: Simple program that finds time complexity? Sounds very complicated.

Comment: Input is a java program.And output is O(n) or O(2n).

Comment: I think "i/p" is some kind of (Indian?) abbreviation for input. Please don't use abbreviations (like "fnd") that most people don't know, user2924908.

Comment: Also counting for loops is way too naive, a for loop does not always denote O(n) complexity. It could well run for n^2 iterations, thus O(n^2).

Comment: Yes.Its too naive.Iknow.But im making a very simple project in determining the now of iteration for for loop.That too in avery short time I have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program/algorithm to find the time complexity of any given program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461168/program-algorithm-to-find-the-time-complexity-of-any-given-program)

Comment: Actually finding the time complexity of the program is difficult.But i need to find it.So I thought of finding it in a very simplified way,which prints the no of iterations of "for" and "while" loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not full proof, but would work for you

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;



public class Complexity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "for(i=0;i<10;i++)\n{\nfor(i=0;i<10;i++)\n{\nfor(i=0;i<10;i++)\n{\n}\n}\n}\nfor(i=0;i<10;i++)\n{\n}\nfor(i=0;i<10;i++)\n{\nfor(i=0;i<10;i++)\n{\n}\n}";
        int open_bracket=0;
        StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(input);
        String result = "";

        String token="";
        int current = 0;

        System.out.println("CODE \n"+input);

        while(t.hasMoreTokens())
        {

            token = t.nextToken();

            if(token.equals("{")) open_bracket++;

            if(token.equals("}")) open_bracket--;

            if(token.length()>=3) if(token.substring(0, 3).equals("for"))  current++;

            if(open_bracket==0&&token.equals("}"))
            {
                result += " n^"+current+" +";
                current = 0;
            }
        }

        if(result.length()>0) result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);

        result = "O( "+result+")";

        System.out.println("RESULT = "+result);

    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
CODE    

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
}
}
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
}
}

RESULT = O(  n^3 + n^1 + n^2 )
```

Comment: Let me know your input.

Comment: Thank you.Thank you so much.Now I  can proceed with this.This is my first time im using this site and i got an answer .So happy

Comment: Please notice how i have defined the input, having "\n" between lines is crucial.

Comment: Ok.Ok.Ive noticed it.Thnk u