# Combining 2 lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists each of equal size and am interested to combine these two lists and write it into a file.

```
alist=[1,2,3,5] 
blist=[2,3,4,5]
```

--the resulting list should be like 
    [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (5,5)]

After that i want that to be written it to a file. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Remove that comma at the end of your first statement. Currently `alist` is a tuple, with value `([1, 2, 3, 5],)`.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803526/merge-two-lists-of-lists-python.  Smells like homework.  Certainly an FAQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
# combine the lists
zipped = zip(alist, blist)

# write to a file (in append mode)
file = open("filename", 'a') 
for item in zipped:
    file.write("%d, %d\n" % item) 
file.close()
```

The resulting output in the file will be:

```
 1,2
 2,3
 3,4
 5,5
```

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, I'll add to [Ben's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673005/combining-2-lists-in-python/1673012#1673012) that `itertools.izip` is preferable especially for larger lists if the result is used iteratively, as the final result is not an actual list but a generator:

```
from itertools import izip
zipped = izip(alist, blist)
with open("output.txt", "wt") as f:
    for item in zipped:
        f.write("{0},{1}\n".format(*item))
```

The documentation for `izip` can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.izip).

Comment: Good point; this is worth doing if you are using 2.6 or earlier. In Python 3, `zip()` produces an iterator rather than a list

Comment: @Ben: Yes, you are right! I didn't mention that for Python 3 but it's worth knowing.