# Linking values from two separate lists

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining 2 lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673005/combining-2-lists-in-python)

I have two lists with the same number of values in each

`[x1,x2....xn]` and `[y1,y2....yn]`

I would like to produce a 3rd list which takes the 1st value from the first list and links it with the first value from the second and then repeats for every value

So that my output would be a list of the form

```
[(x1,y1) (x2,y2)..... (xn, yn)]
```

I assume this is possible and im just missing something quite straightforward?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip(list1, list2)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).