# How to combine two lists, by each element into one?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, and want to combine them into one, by each element:

```
List1 = ['s', 'd', 'c']
List2 = ['a', 'b', 'h']
```

What I would like:

```
List = ['sa', 'db', 'ch']
```

Comment: `[''.join(pair) for pair in zip(List1, List2)]`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into `zip()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining 2 lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673005/combining-2-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[a+b for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) are the savior for you. Try:

```
[''.join(i) for i in zip(List1, List2)]
```

OR you can do:

```
[i + j for i, j in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List1 = ['s', 'd', 'c']
List2 = ['a', 'b', 'h']
ls =[]
for i in range(len(List1)):
    ls.append(List1[i]+List2[i])

print(ls)
```

Comment: Try not to use indices for looping and consider using `enumerate` if you really have to. The loop can be avoided with a list comprehension; it's more efficient.

Comment: thank you for your very good suggestion. I am new to python and on a way to learning. Hopefully next time will be careful about it.