# Setting Up A Recursive Function to Calculate Inclusion Exclusion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

For those of you unfamiliar, the inclusion-exclusion principle sets out a way to determine the values of the union of intersecting sets without double counting.  In short, if you have two sets A,B and they intersect it is possible to calculate the value of their union by adding the values of the two sets together and then subtracting their intersection to avoid double counting.

In other words,

```
 $/mu(A /union B) = /mu(A) + /mu(B) - /mu(A /intersection B)$.
```

This can be extended for any finite number of sets and even for an infinite number of sets.  How might one construct a recursive function in Python that makes use of this principle?

Comment: Could you show us what you first tried?

Comment: @Cilyan Well, to be honest I am not sure where to start.  Do you have any hints on where to get started?

Comment: "makes use of this principle" - to do what? If you want to calculate the size of the union, just take the union. PIE isn't as useful with the kinds of sets we tend to work with in programming.

Comment: @user I suppose the main reason I'm asking is just to satisfy my curiosity about whether this principle can be represented recursively.  In retrospect, it is not strictly a programming problem.  I suppose I posted here just so that I could work towards constructing one myself in order for it to be a bit more practical.  Your point about the difference between sets used in programming and elsewhere is a good one though.

Comment: @Stopwatch: please see point 3 of the off-topic criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Where to start? Search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622493/using-python-how-can-i-merge-or-join-two-lists-so-that-their-values-dont-overl/8622594#8622594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you wouldn't use PIE. If you want the size of the union, take the union:

```
def union_size(sets):
    return len(set.union(*sets))
```

PIE is more useful in combinatorics, where you might have a set of 2 gazillion elements, a set of 3 gazillion elements, and a way to tell that their intersection contains 1 gazillion elements without going through all the elements one by one. In programming, though, you're not working with compact expressions that encode the sets. You have 5 gazillion elements sitting in memory. Intersecting the sets would require going through every one of 2 gazillion elements and seeing whether it's in the other set. There's no advantage to PIE.

If you want to use it anyway, the simplest way would be to use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
def union_size(sets):
    return sum((-1)**(i+1) * len(set.intersection(*subset))
               for i in xrange(1, len(sets) + 1)
               for subset in itertools.combinations(sets, i))
```

Comment: The point about the difference in programming along with a possible method is exactly what I was looking for.  I see that I need to practice a bit more so that I can see these sorts of things immediately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use sets.

```
AuB = set(A).union(B)
len(AuB)
```

You can also use set.intersection if you want AnB.

```
lenAuB = len(A) + len(B) - len(set(A).intersection(B))
```

(I assume A and B have no duplicates items in the last line)

Comment: +1 for introducing these ideas but user's answer provides a more robust explanation of why my ideas about how PIE should work here is wrong.