# sorting list of lists that contain both sorted and unsorted lists

Tags: sorting, merging-data

There are k lists, which contain m unsorted lists (0 <=m < k). How can the lists be merged into a single large list which should also be sorted, No information provided about the lists that are sorted.

Comment: sort the unsorted list before merging them.

Comment: You title talks of "both sorted and unsorted lists", but the description says "k lists, all sorted".  Which is it?  What do you mean by "instead of l(say 2)"?

Comment: i changed the question, thanks Tony !

Comment: in practice just combining the lists and performing a [general sort can be faster (for small total number of items < 1e6) then a specialized algorithm (merge sort)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/482848/4279) despite worse asymptotic time complexity

Answer (score 1):

Suppose n the number of the total elements in all lists.

Assuming this number of elements is distributed equally between all the lists, you can do the follows:

- Sort every unsorted list
- Merge all elements from all lists

Run-time analyze:

The number of elements in each list equals to n/k.

So sorting every unsorted list takes O((n/k)*log(n/k) => run-time for sorting all m lists equals to O(m*(n/k)*log(n/k)).

The merging part takes O(n).

Thus, we get overall run-time = O(n + m*(n/k)*log(n/k)).

Answer (score 0):

you can use insertion sort which would be an easy answer. worst it would run O(n**2) per se.

Otherwise sort (merge, or quicksort) unsorted lists and merge them. based on your m and k you can do some micro optimziation. Here your complexity would be O(nlogn) based on n. you can figure out what it corresponds with k and m.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the unsorted list using randomized quick sort and then merge all the sorted lists using merge sort .