# improving heapq efficiency

Tags: python, performance, heap

So I find myself taking advantage of `heapq` for some calculations.  However, for the problem I am working on, it runs slow because the heap gets pretty big.

I thought I had an option to speed it up.  Rather than creating a giant heap, make it a heap of heaps.  But, surprisingly to me, the "more efficient" code is significantly slower.  There's a bit more overhead in that more efficient code, but I really thought it would win by a lot.  Having stripped down the problem, I've got two functions that do the same net calculation.  `f1` is the "naive" (and faster) version.  `f2` is the "improved" (but slower) version.  I do some random number generation in both, but I use the same seed, so it really is the same thing.

```
import random
import heapq
def f1():
    random.seed(1)
    Q=[0]
    while Q:
        value = heapq.heappop(Q)
        #print value
        if value<0.5:
            for counter in range(16):
                heapq.heappush(Q,value + 0.1 + (random.random()/1000))
    print value

def f2():
    random.seed(1)
    Q=[[0]]
    while Q:
        subQ = heapq.heappop(Q)
        value = heapq.heappop(subQ)
        #print value
        if subQ:
            heapq.heappush(Q,subQ)
        newQ = []
        if value<0.5:
            for counter in range(16):
                newQ.append(value + 0.1 + (random.random()/1000))
            heapq.heapify(newQ)
            heapq.heappush(Q,newQ)
    print value
```

Why does the heap of heaps (`f2`) run significantly slower?  It should call `heappush` the same number of times, and heappop twice as many times.  But the size of the heaps should be significantly smaller, so I expected it to run faster.

Comment: write big-O cost for each operation and compare e.g., heapify(newQ) is O(len(newQ)), heappop(), heappush() are O(log len(Q) * comparison cost) where comparison cost is O(1) for a float and O(len(newQ)) for nested heaps.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  Why would a comparison of two lists be O(len(newQ))?  I would expect it to just look at the first entry in the list and sort by that --- I expected it to be O(1).  (in all the comparisons the lists differ in their first entry)

Comment: if they *always* differ then it is also O(1) and only the constant factor might be different. Try to modify algorithm to encrease the heap size, to see the actual growth polynom ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/482848/4279)).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  -  so it actually does behave the way I was expecting.  But I needed to make the subQs to be really large before the benefit I was after materialized.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I just wasn't pushing the code hard enough.  Here's some modified code.  When the subQ is made very large, the benefit I was after appears.

```
def f1(m,n):
    random.seed(1)
    Q=[0]
    for counter in range(m):
        value = heapq.heappop(Q)
        #print value
        for newcounter in range(n):
            heapq.heappush(Q,random.random())
    print value #should be the same for both methods, so this is just a test
    
def f2(m,n):
    random.seed(1)
    Q=[[0]]
    for counter in range(1000000):
        subQ = heapq.heappop(Q)
        value = heapq.heappop(subQ)
        #print value
        if subQ:
            heapq.heappush(Q,subQ)
        newQ = []
        for newcounter in range(n):
            newQ.append(random.random())
        heapq.heapify(newQ)
        heapq.heappush(Q,newQ)
    print value #should be the same for both methods, so this is just a test
```

When I profile `f1(1000000,10)` and `f2(1000000,10)` I get run times of 10.7 seconds and 14.8 seconds.  The relevant details are:

f1:

> ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
>
> 1000000    1.793    0.000    1.793    0.000 {_heapq.heappop}
>
> 10000000    3.856    0.000    3.856    0.000 {_heapq.heappush}

f2:

> 1000000    1.095    0.000    1.095    0.000 {_heapq.heapify}
>
> 2000000    2.628    0.000    2.628    0.000 {_heapq.heappop}
>
> 1999999    2.245    0.000    2.245    0.000 {_heapq.heappush}
>
> 10000000    1.114    0.000    1.114    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}

So net `f2` loses out because of the extra `heappop`, as well as `heapify` and `append`.  It does better on `heappush`.

But when I go and challenge it with a larger internal loop and run `f1(1000,100000)` and `f2(1000,100000)` we get

f1:

> 1000    0.015    0.000    0.015    0.000 {_heapq.heappop}
>
> 100000000   28.730    0.000   28.730    0.000 {_heapq.heappush}

f2:

> 1000   19.952    0.020   19.952    0.020 {_heapq.heapify}
>
> 2000    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {_heapq.heappop}
>
> 1999    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {_heapq.heappush}
>
> 100000000    6.977    0.000    6.977    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}

So we now do much better on `heappush`, and it's now enough that `f2` runs faster (69 seconds versus 75 seconds).

So it turns out I just hadn't pushed my code sufficiently hard.  I needed things to get large enough that many calls to heappush became slower than many calls to heapify.

Comment: why do you use `range(1000000)` in `f2()` but `range(m)` in `f1()`?

Comment: If `m`,`n` are close then `f2()` should be worse by `O(len(newQ) / log(len(Q)))` -- you should recheck it.

Comment: Optimization for your `f2` code: Change `subQ = heapq.heappop(Q)`, `value = heapq.heappop(subQ)`, `if subQ: heapq.heappush(Q,subQ)` to: `subQ = Q[0]; value = heapq.heappop(subQ)`, `if subQ: heapq.heapreplace(Q, subQ)`, `else: heapq.heappop(Q)`. Since the common case is that you're not clearing the head of `Q`, it's more efficient to use `heapreplace` to restore the heap invariant (definitely legal too; `heapq.merge` uses the same trick of mutating the head and `heapreplace`-ing it) instead of `heappop`-ing when you're usually going to `heappush` it back on. Savings are small but consistent.

Comment: You could also move the replace or pop down, so when you have `newQ` you either replace and push, or just replace (saving an unnecessary pop/push in the emptied heap case). Of course, given how much the code is being run, I see significant savings just caching modules functions into the local namespace before starting the loop so it's direct from local stack instead of global lookup of `heapq`, then lookup of `heapq` attribute.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  why `range(1000000)` --- failure to fix bug found after copy/paste...

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Thanks - that looks useful.

Comment: @Joel: does it invalidate the results?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - no the typo was corrected before I did the calculations - I just hadn't corrected what I had pasted.  Anyways - thanks for the help.  I'm boarding a transpacific flight now...