# Binary search to insert a value to a sorted list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I'm trying to insert values from list B in to list A.

List A is always sorted in descending order and can get quite big (2x10^5).

List B is always sorted in ascending order and can also be of the size 2x10^5

I want to insert the values from B to A whilst still having the descending order. I used binary search to find the index positions of where I should add the value.

However for this one test case I am having a peculiar bug that I can't seem to fix

```
def binarySearch(arr, low, high, x):
    while low < high:
        mid = low + (high - low) // 2;
        if arr[mid] == x:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < x:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    if low >= high:
        return(low)

for i in B:
    indexpos = binarySearch(A, 0, len(A)-1, i)
    if indexpos == 0:
        A = [i] + A
    else:
        A = A[:indexpos+1] + [i] + A[indexpos+1:]
    print(A)
```

Here is a sample input that works:

```
A = [100,100,50,40,40,20,10]
B = [5,25,50,120]

Output: A = [120, 100, 100, 50, 50, 40, 40, 25, 20, 10, 5]
```

I can't figure out why this one doesn't work:

```
A = [100,90,90,80,75,60]
B = [50,65,77,90,102]

Output: A = [102, 100, 90, 90, 90, 80, 75, 77, 65, 60, 50]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Your `while` loop should continue while `low <= high`, and you should `return high`. Only this way you ensure that the returned index has a value that is not greater than `x`.

In the main code you should not have a special case for `indexpos == 0`

So:

```
def binarySearch(arr, low, high, x):
    while low <= high:
        mid = low + (high - low) // 2;
        if arr[mid] == x:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < x:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return high

for i in B:
    indexpos = binarySearch(A, 0, len(A)-1, i)
    A = A[:indexpos+1] + [i] + A[indexpos+1:]

print(A)
```

Note that since you read all values in *A*, each time you make an assignment to *A*, the benefit of binary search is zero: one assignment to *A* costs *O(n)*, where *n* is the size of *A*, while the first binary search "only" costs *O(logn)*. The bottle neck is thus the assignment to A. The time complexity of this algorithm is *O(nm)*, where *n* and *m* are the sizes of both lists.

You should just allocate the necessary extra space for *A* only once, and then move elements from *A* (starting from the last real value in *A*) to the end of the now extended list, while comparing with values from *B* (starting from left to right): either put the value from *A* or *B* there, and work your way through both lists like that.

This will make the process *O(n+m)*.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```
m = len(A)
n = len(B)
k = m + n

# extend A only once
A.extend([0] * n)

# move values to the extended area
m -= 1
for b in B:
    k -= 1
    while m >= 0 and A[m] < b:
        A[k] = A[m]
        k -= 1
        m -= 1
    A[k] = b

print(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve your code, look at trincot's answer; but as he also said, be aware that using a binary search for each element of B is probably not the most efficient method here.

trincot provides a better algorithm and if you want a more pythonic solution you can have a look here: [Combining two sorted lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464342/combining-two-sorted-lists-in-python)

Comment: What does "Also" refer to?

Comment: @trincot I was refering to you, it should be clearer now :)

Comment: Did you read my answer up to the end? I did mention that binary search is not efficient. This was already in my answer in its first version, and that was 30 minutes before you posted your answer... I even added the code for the efficient alternative in an update, also well before you posted your answer.

Comment: Did you read the link I point to? The most efficient pythonic solution in this case is probably just  `A += B; A.sort()`

Comment: I am referring to the first paragraph of your answer. You make it sound as if I only provided an improvement of the OP's code and did not mention that a binary search is not efficient.

Comment: modified. Do you like it better?