# Merging two sorted python lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to merge two user inputted lists that have been sorted in descending order. I understand how to merge two lists then sort, however i'm struggling the other way around.

```
# user list input
a = [int(x) for x in input("List 1: ").split()]
b = [int(y) for y in input("List 2: ").split()]

a.sort(reverse=True)
b.sort(reverse=True)

print(a + b)
```

For example, I want to input: `[1, 3, 3, 6]` &  `[1, 4, 5]`, and my output be: `[6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1]`

Comment: `c = sorted(a + b, reverse=True)` and then `print(c)`

Comment: Are you doing this because you *want a sorted list* or because you *want to learn to write a merge*? If you want a sorted list, just concatenate and sort. If you want to learn to write a merge, go read about mergesorts and look at how the merge step works.

Comment: If you're here to learn to write a merge, you're not going to learn much just from us dumping code on you. You'll have something to copy-paste, but copy-pasting doesn't help you understand how an algorithm works or help you learn to write your own code.

Comment: Yes im trying to write a merge. I understand how to combine the two then sort the lists.

Comment: I learn from reading code and understanding how it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining two sorted lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464342/combining-two-sorted-lists-in-python). There's an implementation without using stdlib modules a few answers down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) for this. It takes multiple sorted iterables and merges them into a single sorted output, so:

```
c = list(heapq.merge(
    sorted(a, reverse=True),
    sorted(b, reverse=True),
    reverse=True)
```

Note that this works also with iterables (e.g. lazily-calculated, potentially consumable objects), which is when you are more likely to use it (when combining sorted iterables).

I am assuming you get the lists pre-sorted or you just want to know how to do this, since it would probably be preferable to merge the lists first and then sort them (either with `sorted`  or mutating them with `.sort()`).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `sorted()`.

```
# user list input
a = [int(x) for x in input("List 1: ").split()]
b = [int(y) for y in input("List 2: ").split()]
print(sorted(a+b,reverse=True))
```

inp/out

```
List 1: 1 2 3 
List 2: 1 2 3
[3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment BuddyBob. However, i'm trying to merge the two inputs THEN sort them..

Comment: why? This seems to work perfectly fine? Anyways this does that just quicker. a+b merges them. sorted sorts the merged list. @patgoldgold

Comment: It's for a specific coding reason.. i know it's unnecessarily haha!